# Explanation for snippet in TCP/IP sockets in C

Tags: c, unix, code-snippets

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    short s[2];
} MSG;

MSG *mp,m= {4, 1, 0};
char *fp, *tp;
mp = (MSG *) malloc(sizeof(MSG));
for(fp=(char*)m.s, tp=(char *)mp->s; tp <(char *)(mp+1);)
    *tp++ = *fp++;
```

This is a code snippet found in TCP/IP Sockets in C by Donahoo and Calvert can anyone please provide a detailed explanation of the code ? I would be really grateful as I have to explain this code snippet to other people and I am not where near the level of understanding that I can teach this to someone.

Comment: If you don't understand it, why teach it to someone?

Comment: You also copied it wrong.

Comment: I am sorry, if I copied it wrong. I can't seem to find my mistake. If you may point it out that would be great. Also, I just felt that if I could teach someone, I will better understand it.

Comment: The for loop could be more clearly written as  `memcpy(mp->s, m.s, sizeof(MSG) - offsetof(MSG, s));`

Comment: @Chris Hello, thank you for the clarification. I will be really grateful if you could explain what is wrong with the previous method and how your snip solves it. I believe as stated by David it steers clear of the ambiguity issue.

Comment: @cRAYonhere: There's nothing "wrong" with it -- it's just obfuscated.  It's (just) a copy of part of a struct (from a certain member to the end, including any padding that may be present), which is more clearly expressed as a simple `memcpy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code simply copies `m.s` to `mp->s`.

Your code snippet declares a struct typedeffed (aliased) to `MSG`. It then declares a pointer to struct `*mp` and declares struct `m` initialized setting  `m.a = 4;` and attempting incorrectly to set `m.s[0] = 1;` and `m.s[1] = 0;`. Two character pointers (a *from-pointer*) `fp` and (a *to-pointer*) `tp`. Space is then allocated for 1 struct and the address assigned to `mp`.

The `for` loop simply sets the *from-pointer* `fp` to point to the beginning of `m.s[0]`, and the *to-pointer* `tp` to point to `mp->s[0]`. The test clause insures that iterating stops after the bytes in `mp` (between `mp->s[0]` and the end of `mp`) are traversed. `*tp++ = *fp++;` simply copies the byte pointed to by `fp` to the corresponding byte pointed to by `tp` and uses the *post-increment* operator to advance the pointer to the next byte in each. (there is an argument that the assignment could be better written as `*tp = *fp++`; and the increment of `tp` preformed in the `for` statement due to ambiguity (lack of guarantee) in the order of dereference and increment), e.g.

```
for (fp=(char*)m.s, tp=(char *)mp->s; tp <(char *)(mp+1); tp++)
    *tp = *fp++;
```

That said, a corrected and annotated version of the code in your question could be written as follows:

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    short s[2];
} MSG;

MSG *mp, m = {4, {1, 0}};
char *fp, *tp;
mp = malloc (sizeof *mp);
for(fp=(char*)m.s, tp=(char *)mp->s; tp <(char *)(mp+1);)
    *tp++ = *fp++;
```

A short example (substituting `8` for `0` to make clear what is happening) could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    short s[2];
} MSG;

int main (void) {

    MSG *mp, m = {4, {1, 8}};
    char *fp, *tp;

    mp = malloc (sizeof *mp);   /* allocate mem for one struct */
    for (fp = (char*)m.s,       /* fp points to first byte of 2 in m.s   */
        tp = (char*)mp->s;      /* tp points to first byte of 2 in mp->s */
        tp < (char*)(mp+1);)    /* test tp within mp (mp->s actually )   */
        *tp++ = *fp++;          /* copy m.s to mp->s */

    printf ("m.a   %d, m.s[0]   %hd, m.s[1]   %hd\n", m.a, m.s[0], m.s[1]);
    printf ("mp->a %d, mp->s[0] %hd, mp->s[1] %hd\n", mp->a, mp->s[0], mp->s[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/snip
m.a   4, m.s[0]   1, m.s[1]   8
mp->a 0, mp->s[0] 1, mp->s[1] 8
```

Look over the explanation and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain the nitty gritties of the whole thing. If you will be kind enough to answer 2 of my queries.
1. `mp->s` can you explain a bit on this snip.
2. "The test clause insures that iterating stops after the bytes in `mm` are traversed. " and do you mean mp ?

Comment: Sure, 1. When you access a structure, through a struct variable, you use the *dot* operator, (e.g. `m.s`), but when you have a *pointer to a struct*, you use the *arrow operator* (e.g. `mp->s`).  This might make your head hurt, but `m.s == (&m)->s` and `mp->s == (*mp).s`. Think about both cases.  Yes, the `mm` is just a typo from my fumble fingers and 10 year old keyboard `:)`